# Why is !important required to override link styling when the class should?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create re-usable styling for in-page navigation. There is a default style, assigned by ID to the enclosing <nav> element. I also need to have an alternate style for certain special <a> elements within that <nav> element.

I assigned a class to one <a> element and then attempted to style it to mixed success. Some properties changed, but others only if I force an override with "!important".

While I can get by with this, it feels like a hack. What am I'm missing to properly target these specific links?

```css
#page-nav a {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    padding: .25rem .5rem;
    line-height: 2.25;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
}
#page-nav a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
a.pageNavAlt:link {
    background-color: black;              /* WORKS        */
    /* color: red;                           DOESN'T WORK */
    color: red !important;                /* WORKS        */
}
a.pageNavAlt:hover { 
    /* background-color: darkred;
    color: yellow;                           DOESN'T WORK */
    background-color: darkred !important; /* WORKS        */
    color: yellow !important;             /* WORKS        */
}
```

```html
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a class="pageNavAlt" href="#">Alternate link</a> <a href="#">Standard link 1</a> <a href="#">Standard link 2</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `#page-nav a` (and `#page-nav a:hover`) have higher precedence in the CSS rules due to the use of an `id`.  So the styles in `a.pageNavAlt:hover` *are* being applied, but are being over-ruled by the styles in `#page-nav a:hover`.

You can add the `id` selector to the additional styles:

```css
#page-nav a {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: .3rem;
    padding: .25rem .5rem;
    line-height: 2.25;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
}
#page-nav a:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
#page-nav a.pageNavAlt:link { /* <-- here */
    background-color: black;
    color: red;
}
#page-nav a.pageNavAlt:hover {  /* <-- and here */
    background-color: darkred;
    color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<nav id="page-nav">
    <a class="pageNavAlt" href="#">Alternate link</a> <a href="#">Standard link 1</a> <a href="#">Standard link 2</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and sample code.

I incorrectly assumed that a style applied to a child would supersede an ID on a parent...and I don't think I would have ever intuited that syntax without your example.

Comment: @JosephMoore: If you haven’t seen it before, this is also a good opportunity to use the DOM explorer in your browser’s development tools.  One of the things it shows is the CSS rules applied, where they came from, and in order of precedence.